# Transparent render problem

Tags: rendering, transparency

My transparent object show jungle?

Every time I make transparent object there is always a reflection of a jungle. why? how do I get normal transparent object?

[image]

Comment: The reflection you are seeing is that of a hidden HDRI image which provides both lighting and reflections to the scene. You are seeing this because you are in Material Preview (aka "LookDev") mode which uses a simpler render engine as well as HDRI reflections in order to give a "fast preview" of your textured objects. To see the proper rendered preview (without the "jungle"), switch from Material Preview to Rendered preview (farthest right of the four little circles in top right), or by selecting from the pie menu after pressing Z.

Comment: Thx you very much.

Answer (score 2):

In the  "Material Preview" viewport shading blender shows you the object and uses an internal environment map to light the scene.

In the Shading dropdown menu
[image]

you can choose which environment map to use
[image]

or you can choose to use the scene World
[image]
but in this last case you'll need to set the world properly in the node editor (or in the proporties panel).

You also need to have something around and behind the object to reflect/transmit it.

Comment: Thx you very much

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Is there any complete guide on node?

Comment: I think so. Search on YouTube for "blender world node editor" (specific for the world, considering your question). There should be a lot of stuff.